# About generating makefile prerequisites automatically

Tags: c, makefile

I'm working on Stanford CS107  assignment 3, in which we implement a C version "vector". In the end I have some files in my directory,

```
.
├── Makefile
├── bool.h
├── vector.c
├── vector.h
└── vectortest.c
```

My question is about the handout Makefile, which looks like that,

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=gnu11 -Wpointer-arith
LDFLAGS = 

VECTOR_SRCS = vector.c
VECTOR_HDRS = $(VECTOR_SRCS:.c=.h)

VECTOR_TEST_SRCS = vectortest.c $(VECTOR_SRCS)
VECTOR_TEST_OBJS = $(VECTOR_TEST_SRCS:.c=.o)

SRCS = $(VECTOR_SRCS) vectortest.c
HDRS = $(VECTOR_HDRS)  

EXECUTABLES = vector-test 

default: $(EXECUTABLES)

vector-test: Makefile.dependencies $(VECTOR_TEST_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(VECTOR_TEST_OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

# The dependencies below make use of make's default rules,
# under which a .o automatically depends on its .c and
# the action taken uses the $(CC) and $(CFLAGS) variables.
# These lines describe a few extra dependencies involved.
Makefile.dependencies:: $(SRCS) $(HDRS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $(SRCS) > Makefile.dependencies

-include Makefile.dependencies

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -fr $(EXECUTABLES) *.o core Makefile.dependencies
```

When I run `make vector-test`, a file `Makefile.dependencies` was generated, in which lies some "default rules" of make,

```
vector.o: vector.c vector.h bool.h
vectortest.o: vectortest.c vector.h bool.h
```

My question is: professor keep the result of preprocess in another file **is just to show us what the "default rules" is, or it's for some efficiency reason?** For example [GNU-GCC-3.22 Using Precompiled Headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) can save times by preventing compile from processing header files over and over again? Because normally we don't have to list all `.h` files, and simply do `gcc -c vector.c`, or leave everything to the implicit rules. Am I right?

Another question is why he use `::` instead of `:` here?  I didn't find some useful information online talking about that. Thanks guys!

Comment: About `::`: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon

Comment: Thx for the quick response. So that means we can have more than one rules about the same target `Makefile.dependencies` if necessary?

Comment: If you have only one source file, it's not a big deal to recompile all the time.  If you have 200 source files and 200 header files and some source files include one header and some include 12 different headers and some include 50 different headers (maybe they include only a few headers directly but those headers include other headers, etc.) then you don't want to recompile all of them all the time, but it can be a major undertaking to ensure that all the headers are defined properly as prerequisites... and it's extremely error-prone.  So, these rules ask the compiler to track it for you.

Comment: Thx @MadScientist ! Just to mention another great doc from https://mad-scientist.net : [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/), which perfectly explained how and why to use `gcc -MM` to create an old-school dependencies file, and another modern way of using `.d` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> professor keep the result of preprocess in another file

Not true. According to your `makefile`, preprocessing result is not stored in any files. Preprocessing is a result of running preprocessor on your source files, i.e. it will substitute the contents of header files in place of `#include` directives and evaluate and substitute macros.

Instead, in your `makefile`, a header dependency rules are generated and stored in `Makefile.dependencies`. The `-MM` key of `gcc` generates header dependency rules, so that in case you edit one of the header files on which your source files depend, those source files will be recompiled next time you invoke `make`.

In your `makefile` you then include the generated dependency rules with `-include Makefile.dependencies`, so that `make` picks up header dependency rules generated by previous `make` invocation.
The contents of `Makefile.dependencies`, as you have noticed, are a valid `makefile` syntax.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html for more info.

So, this is kind of efficiency reasons, so that you can avoid rebuilding all, by cleaning first in case some of the header files are edited. But also, it is a convenience reason, that you don't have to worry about remembering to clean and rebuild all in case you have edited some of the header files. The `make` utility will rebuild only affected source files.

*Precomiled headers* is not related to that.

Comment: Thx @igagis, the reference is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @igagis and @MadScientist for following great references:

1. [Mad-Scientist.net - Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)
2. [GNU - Generating Prerequisites Automatically](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html)
3. [GNU - How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html#Remaking-Makefiles)

The follow content is just a simple conclusion of [Mad-Scientist.net - Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/), for more information please check the original link.

In short, there are two conventional practices to generate prerequisites automatically,

1. Old-school way is to use `gcc -MM` to create a single dependencies file.

```
    vector.o: vector.c vector.h bool.h
    vectortest.o: vectortest.c vector.h bool.h
```

The code snippet looks like,

```
    depend:: $(SRCS) $(HDRS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $(SRCS) $(LDFLAGS) > $(DEP_FILE)

    -include $(DEP_FILE)
```

This practice has two main problems:

- You have to explicitly run `make depend` to keep dependencies file up to date.
- It is inefficient to rebuild all dependencies if any tiny change is made in source code, especially when you have a large scale project to manage.

2. A second modern way solves above problems by separating each dependency rule into one `.d` file.

In `vector.d`:

```
vector.o vector.d: vector.c vector.h bool.h
```

In `vectortest.d`

```
vectortest.o vectortest.d: vectortest.c vector.h bool.h
```

The point here is that when `make` read the above rule in `.d` file, before it does anything, it will try to rebuild included `.d` file automatically, and that makes the difference. People don't have to explicitly run `make depend`.

The following snippet is not the final version but to give you a little taste about what the code looks like. There are some little tricks hiding behind, check the references above for complete solution.

```
    %.d: %.c
        @set -e; rm -f $@; \
         $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
         sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
         rm -f $@.$$$$

    -include $(wildcard $(SRCS:.c=.d))
```

Currently I feel comfortable with the first practice, because it's quite simple and good enough for most of my personal use case. And here is the complete `Makefile` for this assignment.

```
# 1. C11 is the newest version of C language
# 2. -Wpointer-arith request a warning when addtion and subtraction are done
# on pointers to void and to functions, which is supported in GNU C.

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=gnu11 -Wpointer-arith
LDFLAGS = 

VECTOR_SRCS = vector.c
VECTOR_HDRS = $(VECTOR_SRCS:.c=.h)
VECTOR_OBJS = $(VECTOR_SRCS:.c=.o)  

VECTOR_TEST_SRCS = vectortest.c $(VECTOR_SRCS)
VECTOR_TEST_OBJS = $(VECTOR_TEST_SRCS:.c=.o)

SRCS = $(VECTOR_SRCS) vectortest.c
HDRS = $(VECTOR_HDRS)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o) 

EXES = vectortest

DEP_DIR = ./deps
DEP_FILE = $(DEP_DIR)/Makefile.dependencies

.PHONY: default depend clean

default: $(EXES)

# 1. The dependencies below make use of make's default rules,
# under which a .o automatically depends on its .c and
# the action taken uses the $(CC) and $(CFLAGS) variables.
# These lines describe a few extra dependencies involved.
#
# 2. -MMD means write a dependencies file containing user headers.
# -MM likes -MMD, but also implies -E only do preprocess,
# and write to stand out by default.

depend:: $(SRCS) $(HDRS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $(SRCS) $(LDFLAGS) > $(DEP_FILE)

-include $(DEP_FILE)

vectortest: $(VECTOR_TEST_OBJS) depend
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(VECTOR_TEST_OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    -rm -f *.o  $(EXES) $(DEP_FILE)
```